# PVC Water line keeps getting pin holes

Tags: water, leak, boiler

The water line that goes from my boiler, carrying warm water keeps getting pin hole leaks. The line is a standard flexible white plastic insulated pipe, covered in a red mantle.

[image: What the line looks like]

About a year ago, I discovered the first pinhole leak, spraying water into the mantle. The result was a big pool of water under my floor. A plumber came by and replaced part of the pipe with a new part.

And what do you know... A little while after, a new leak appeared, about 10CM below the original leak. The plumber came back and replaced an even bigger part of the pipe.

Now, again, the same water line is leaking... the leak is just below the replaced part, leaking water into the mantle...

The plumber ensures me it's just a faulty pipe. The problem is that the whole line is not exposed, so it would be very difficult to replace it in its entirety.

The pipe is the same brand as all the other water lines of my water system. Only this one keeps rupturing. What is going on?

Could there be too much pressure on the line? Could it be the water hardness is too high for the line?

I'm really worried about having to tear open everything to fix this thing once and for all.

Please assist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PVC is not rated for hot water, so I wonder whether that's actually what you have (which would be a problem) or whether you have misidentified the pipe type.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have added explanations to my question. Sorry for caulc, it's a wrong translation: when the water has too much calcium in it, I mean. I'm talking about water hardness... Does that make sense?

Comment: Markings on the pipe should help identify what it is made of, that might be useful information to add to your question.

Comment: It's probably polyethylene (as in PEX), no?